# gcc upgrade caused static local variable of template function to become unknow

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I'm upgrading our gcc from gcc 4.1.2 to gcc 4.9.4.

I first compiled with gcc4.9, and start the program, seeing error below:

```
user@machine:~/bin> Load BusinessSoCfg, Name GameSvr, Dll ../SO/so, CreateFunc CreateBusinessSo
Open Dll ../SO/so failed, ../SO/so: undefined symbol: _ZZN6CTable24IsGameTableSOSupportFuncIM5IGameFiisiiP13tagSOItemInfoEEEbT_E7pHandle
```

pHandle is a static variable defined in template function. 
code is like this:

```
template<class TPMF>
bool CTable::IsGameTableSOSupportFunc(TPMF pfunc)
{
     static void *pHandle = NULL;
     // somethign todo
     return true;
}
```

on our test env(gcc4.1.2), nm -C so shows following, saying symbol is unknow type

```
0000000004d1d9d0 ? bool CTable::IsGameTableSOSupportFunc<int (IGame::*)(int, short, int, int, tagSOItemInfo*)>(int (IGame::*)(int, short, int, int, tagSOItemInfo*))::pHandle
```

but on the compile env(gcc4.9.4) nm -C so shows following, shows symbol is defined

```
0000000004d1d9d0 u bool CTable::IsGameTableSOSupportFunc<int (IGame::*)(int, short, int, int, tagSOItemInfo*)>(int (IGame::*)(int, short, int, int, tagSOItemInfo*))::pHandle
```

what's more, the gcc4.9.4 was compile from souce code with gcc4.1.2 with configure below:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/data/gcc-4.9.4/ --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-lto --enable-vtable-verify --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada
```

**causion:The example below is not showing the same result as described above**

example:

```
//singleton.hpp, must be a hpp
// if singleton was defined in the same file with main,everything goes fine
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


template <class TYPE>
class CSingleton
{
public:
    static TYPE* Instance(void)
    {
        if(m_pSingleton == NULL)
        {
            CSingleton *pTmpCSingleton = new CSingleton;
            m_pSingleton = pTmpCSingleton;
        }
        return &m_pSingleton->m_stInstance;
    }
protected:
    TYPE m_stInstance;
    static CSingleton<TYPE>* m_pSingleton;
};

template <class TYPE>
CSingleton<TYPE>* CSingleton<TYPE>::m_pSingleton = NULL;

// main.cpp
// if singleton was defined in the same file with main,everything goes fine
#include "singleton.hpp" 
#include <stdio.h>
typedef CSingleton<int> s;
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", *s::Instance());
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with gcc4.9,and run the result is :`0`

but  when i copied the binary to gcc4.1.2 machine, excution will core.

```
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

fathermore nm -C will show somehing wrong:

```
nm: a.out: File format not recognized
```

but readelf on both machine works fine:

```
ELF Header:
Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Class:                             ELF64
Data:                              2's complement, little endian
Version:                           1 (current)
OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
ABI Version:                       0
Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
Version:                           0x1
Entry point address:               0x400520
Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
Start of section headers:          3072 (bytes into file)
Flags:                             0x0
Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
Number of program headers:         8
Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
Number of section headers:         30
Section header string table index: 27
```

Comment: a compiler's bug?

Comment: cause i'm not sure how to upgrade gcc from source code. i'm still wondering if it's caused by bad  gcc/g++ tool chain.

Comment: Can you create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: added a simple sscce, which will core on old machine

Comment: your example is not the same as what you wrote above

Comment: yes i know, but the example is  supposed to be the same.

Comment: Are you saying that you compiled on one machine, and copied the binary to another with different environment?

Comment: yes. the gcc of the compile machine is compiled from source code by myself. i'm wondering it's because i didn't set up the right gcc tool chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's caused by gcc upgrade. the binary compiled from higher gcc version use gnu hash. but the binutil of the runing computer doesn't recognize that. recompile with `-Wl,--hash-style=both` or `-Wl,--hash-style=sysv` can solve this.

if i looked at the core file early i could figure this out quicker.